# How to write excel sheets to existing files with filenames that correlate to the sheets with Python

Tags: python

I have one excel file with multiple sheets (let's call this the 'Master' file.) Each sheet a list in columns A, B. I have a file path with multiple files, with names similar to that of the sheets in the 'Master' file. The names are similar, containing specific text, but not exactly the same.
I would like to be able to export each sheet from the Master file to the files in the file path with the corresponding text.

How can I achieve this using python? I have not tried any code yet because I can't find anything that seems to be exactly what I need.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a minimal working example of your problem, namely an example Excel file and the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

you may use pandas to read the excel file, iterate the sheets and save each one to different path.

this code sample [based of asongtoruin's answer in 'Python Loop through Excel sheets, place into one df
'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549110/python-loop-through-excel-sheets-place-into-one-df):

```
import pandas as pd

sheets_dict = pd.read_excel('master_file.xlsx', sheetname=None)

for name, sheet in sheets_dict.items():
    sheet.to_excel("directory/" + name)
```