# How to combine only first and last column from each Excel sheet into new excel using panas in python?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have an `excel` file that consist of multiple sheets (~100sheets) and 8 columns. I am trying to combine my 1st column which is "date", and my last column "prediction" from each sheet into new excel file. Thus, my new excel file should have "date" and "prediction" column for each and every sheet into a single sheet, with multiple prediction columns. For doing this, my thought process was to read file first than use `pandas concat()` to concate the "prediction" column. But when I did that python generated lot of `NaN's`. I was curious, if we can achieve this much better way.

```
**Sheet 1:**
Date    col1    Col2 .....   Prediction1
01/01     9         5               5
02/01     3         7               5

**Sheet2**
Date    col1    Col2 .....   Prediction2
01/01     9         5               4
02/01     3         7               6
```

Note: I am new to python, provide explanation with your code.

**Code:**

```
  #Reading file
  df=pd.read_excel('myexcel.xlsx")

  #Combining files
  excel_combine=pd.concat(df[frame] for frame in df.keys())
```

**Expected Output:**

```
    Date       Prediction1         Prediction2
    01/01            5               4
    02/01            5                6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Loop through Excel sheets, place into one df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549110/python-loop-through-excel-sheets-place-into-one-df)

Comment: @Chris..Thanks,but this question doesn't answer my question..I would like to merge the sheets based on dates that is common between each sheets. please see updated question

Comment: Was writing an answer but you just changed the question completely.

Comment: Use drop to only keep the first and last columns from each sheet and then combine.

Comment: @sid sorry about that. The reason I updated question, was because it was tagged as possible duplicate. Would it be possible for you to show how drop will work ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a dataframe with all your prediction columns neatly renamed.
Concatenating will not always give you the best results. Maybe try merge instead.
Also check out the pandas doc on this topic here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

```
import xlrd
import pandas

# Open the workbook
bk = xlrd.open_workbook('input_file_name')

# set counter to zero
n = 0

# loop through the sheet names
for i in bk.sheet_names():
   # read one sheet into a df at a time
   temp_df = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name = i)
   # set a new column name according to which sheet the prediction came from
   new_col_name = 'pred_' + i
   # rename the prediction column
   temp_df.rename(columns = {'predition' : new_col_name}, inplace = True)

   n += 1 # add one to counter each time a new sheet is processed

   if n == 1:
      # if this is the first loop a dtaframe called df is created
      df = temp_df.copy()

   else:
      # if it is not the first loop merge the temp_df with the df table
      df = df.merge(temp_df,
                    on = 'date',
                    how = 'left') # assuming you do have equal time series for all predictions I set a left join, otherwise a outer join may be better - look this up if you don't know it

# check df if everything is there
print df.info()
print df.head()
print df.describe()

# write to excel
df.to_excel('your_file_name', index = False)
```

Comment: there seems to be an indentation issues from line n+=1

Comment: @biggboss2019 there was a mistake, my bad. it needs to be "... n == 1:" for the if statement