# How to iterate through date header of excel sheet using pandas in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I have an excel sheet how can i iterate through the date as i want to iterate to each row. but there are two headers. i have attached a pic below. one headers is of date. and another header is some timing in , out time, total hours, etc. so each date has 7 columns. so there are 30 days. i want to store the date some where in a variable as i can know which month is this. and then i want to read the value in the header of each date. and do some functionality.
I am using python and panda library

````
_____________|____________|        7/16/19                    |        8/16/19                     |        9/16/19                     |        10/16/19                   |        11/16/19                    | ....
Employee Name|Employee ID |in-time|out-time|total-hours|status||in-time|out-time|total-hours|status||in-time|out-time|total-hours|status|in-time|out-time|total-hours|status||in-time|out-time|total-hours|status|
Shrey        | SHAA       | 5:00  | 13:00  |8        | WO   | ..................................................................................
asd   | dh  |  ...................................................................................
asf   | ge  |  ....................................................................................
asdfd   | ew  |  ...................................................................................
afdsfds   | er  |  ......................................................................................```
````

Comment: Do anyone know how can i check which date is this as it is in header. and according to date i have to iterate

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to find on google how to do this? You will find a lot of examples!
Also you can look here: [Python Loop through Excel sheets, place into one df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549110/python-loop-through-excel-sheets-place-into-one-df)

Comment: How can i loop through according to date because there are two headers. It's not a excel sheet it's data only

Comment: "I have an excel sheet how can i iterate through the date as i want to iterate to each row." this is what I readed!

Comment: and first: find out what type of date this is.

Comment: Sorry in excel this type of data is the example you are showing tell about changing the sheets. as i don't want to work on different sheets as i only have one sheet and there is a  data in it which look like the above way i have added. as this date contains 6 block of in time, out time, etc. so i just want to get specific data of specific date. can you tell how ?