# How to combine multiple excel worksheets into a single Pandas Dataframe with sheet name as the first column and row number as the second column

Tags: python, dataframe, worksheet

I have an Excel workbook that contains 20+ sheets with various sheet names, e.g. sheet1, abc, xyz, etc. I would like to import all sheets into one DataFrame and use the sheet name as the first column and the row number of each sheet as the second column.

The expected result will be like this:

| Sheet | Row | Column1 | Column2 | ...ColumnN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sheet1 | 1 | data | data | data |
| sheet1 | 2 | data | data | data |
| sheet1 | 3 | data | data | data |
| sheet1 | 4 | data | data | data |
| abc | 1 | data | data | data |
| abc | 2 | data | data | data |
| abc | 3 | data | data | data |
| xyz | 1 | data | data | data |
| xyz | 2 | data | data | data |
| ... | ... | data | data | data |

Comment: have you tried anything? what didn't work? there are lots of questions already on this site that describe 1) reading from excel, 2) assign values to columns, and 3) concatenating dataframes

Comment: Thank you. I've done by revising from asongtoruin, answered Jun 14 '17 at 15:46, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549110/python-loop-through-excel-sheets-place-into-one-df

Answer (score 0):

I've revised the code from asongtoruin, answered Jun 14 '17 at 15:46, [Python Loop through Excel sheets, place into one df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549110/python-loop-through-excel-sheets-place-into-one-df)

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None) #T: Print an entire pandas DataFrame. Source: Kite, retrieved on 29 Sep 2021, https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-print-an-entire-pandas-dataframe-in-python

vstPathFile = r"D:\.......\filename.xlsm"

sheets_dict = pd.read_excel(vstPathFile, sheet_name=None, header=None)

full_table = pd.DataFrame()
for name, sheet in sheets_dict.items():
    sheet.insert(loc=0, column="Sheet", value=name, allow_duplicates=True)
    sheet.insert(loc=1, column="Row", value=sheet.index+1, allow_duplicates=True)
    full_table = full_table.append(sheet)

full_table.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```